# Small backpack that can be attached to a bigger one, does it exist?

Tags: backpacks

I normally carry a very small backpack around but when I need my laptop or something else bigger, I grab the bigger one:

[image]

The problem is that I then need to move a lot of things from the small one to the big one or have duplicates (painkillers I can duplicate; notebook and glasses, I need to remember to move).

Is there a solution around these sizes where I can attach the smaller backpack to the bigger one?

I thought something like the [Mira 2-in-1 Pack](http://www.511tactical.com/mira-2-in-1.html), but the problem there is that the detachable pouch is not a backpack but a sort of messenger bags.

Another alternative I thought of something like this:

http://www.eod-gear.com/warrior-assault-systems-load-bearing-molle-harness-with-rear-panel/

and use a molle pouch as small backpack and have a normal backpack with molle weaving to attach it to. But it looks way too clunky.

Comment: See [on-topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) regarding questions about "shopping" and "best thing" -- stackexchange websites are not designed for that and are not a suitable place for those types of questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the only possible answers are "yes", "no" and product recommendations.

Comment: Yes, [it does exist](https://www.mec.ca/en/product/5035-332/Supercontinent-65-Travel-Pack).

Comment: The keyword to search for here is "detachable daypack".